# Repartitioned, but stil out of space on VMWare Ubuntu 13.04 64 Bit

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, vmware, gparted

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64 Bit on VMWare 5.0.2. I am having disk space issues despite growing the linux partition from 30GB to 300GB.

The process I used to increase the size of the disk was to first allocate additional disk space in VMWare, then boot to the gparted live cd and allocate that extra space to /dev/sda1.

An output from df -h shows the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       295G  280G  6.2M 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           395M  396K  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  848K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Usinge Disk Usage Analyzer (gksudo baobab), I see that my home folder is using 100% of space. This equals 292.0 GB. However, no folder within my home folder comes close to adding up to 292 GB.

I have also tried rebooting to the GParted live CD and running the "check" command to fix any errors. However, the space results are the same.

Any ideas what needs to be changed here in order for Ubuntu to correctly recognize the free space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer and will post it here for others to use.

Once I had run GParted and checked the drive for errors, I needed to compress the drive in VMWare before loading the virtual machine. After doing so, the out of space errors went away.

So in order to add space to the main partition in an Ubuntu virtual machine:

1. Add space in VMWare tools
2. Boot to a live cd of GParted and increase the size of your partition. (This may involve multiple steps if you need to shift partitions around to get to the continuous free space).
3. Run the check command in GParted to find any errors in your newly enlarged partition.
4. Close the virtual machine (Currently in GParted)
5. Open the virtual machine settings and compress the drive (this will take a while).
6. Reboot into the normal OS. Everything should be working. Use disk usage analyzer to verify the sizes and space are correct.

Hopefully, this will be useful to others who run into the same issue.